# Redirection in RubyOnRails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssl, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I just got an SSL certificate for "example.com". After making some configurations in NGINX I could finally redirect "http://www.example.com" calls and "http://example.com" calls to "https://example.com". Everything works fine, but when I type "https://www.example.com" an SSL error is shown. Is there a way to redirect "https://www.example.com" calls to "https://example.com" using some Ruby code?

Comment: This isn't solvable at the rails level - your rails code only runs after a connection has been established - any ssl errors will already have occurred.

Answer (score 0):

Handling the redirect at the Rack level and not inside of the Rails app is my preferred way to solve this requirement.

https://github.com/jtrupiano/rack-rewrite#scheme

The link takes you to the part of the README that addresses this question.  I've used this gem in the past and it works really well.

Comment: You did not explain the problem, and you did not offer an answer (though you did provide a link). That could put this answer in jeopardy of deletion. The review queue is full of similar answers. They get added automatically based on heuristics.

Comment: Sorry about that I'll improve my answer.